# how to clean up jobs in teamcity when the job is cancelled

Tags: teamcity

I have a teamcity build that submits a job to the farm.
However, when i cancel the build, the teamcity job is cancelled, but the job is in the farm is still running.

Is there a way to 'inject' some command so that i could do some cleanup and kill the job in the farm when the TC job is cancelled?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

- Update the current configuration to have a variable called "BuildCompleted" which is set to false by default. As the final step in the current configuration, set the variable to true using [service messages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/build-script-interaction-with-teamcity.html).
- Create a separate configuration which does whatever cleanup you need
- Add a "finish build trigger" and a snapshot dependency from the new configuration to the job you are cancelling
- Check the value of the variable from the dependency as the first step in your new build configuration. If the value is true, stop the build from going any further (again, use service messages).
- If the build isn't stopped, the second build step will do your cleanup.